# how to post nsmutable array in php web services

Tags: ios, arrays, web-services

I am first time post array in php websevices , i can't understand How to get my array in php side 
please check my code where i do mistake  , i am using GET method 
here is my iOS Code

i have Create my array like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [yourMutableDictionary setObject:self.btn_absen_from_date.titleLabel.text forKey:@"from"];
    [yourMutableDictionary setObject:self.btn_absen_to_date.titleLabel.text forKey:@"to"];
    [yourMutableDictionary setObject:txt_Reason_absence.text forKey:@"reason"];

    [ary_absence addObject:yourMutableDictionary];



 NSLog(@"%@",ary_absence);




    NSString *tmpValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:test,ary_absence];
    NSString *tmpURL = [SITE_URL stringByAppendingString:tmpValue];
    NSString* encodedUrl = [tmpURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                            NSASCIIStringEncoding];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];

    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    [connnection start];
```

my nsmutable array look like this when i am print using NSLOG

```
(
        {
        from = "03/February/2015";
        reason = Sdfdsfdsfdsfdsffd;
        to = "03/March/2015";
    },
        {
        from = "03/April/2015";
        reason = Sdfdsfdsfds;
        to = "03/April/2015";
    }
)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking - please elaborate on your problem, post current results and expected results and what have you so far tried to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: He want deserialise data on server side. But this is very strange format not like PHP structures - so or change format, or you should parse it on server side. Try <?php var_dumpt($_GET['children_absence']);?> at first

Comment: i have create a array with key value from, to and Reason and this three field use in php backend side , so how to this array get in php